# vector subscript out of range c чем это связано?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Ребят помогите с чем связана такая ошибка? Почему выходит за рэндж. Заметил во многих программах моих появляется когда использую большие числа. В чем дело?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector <int> arr(n * 2 - 1);
    vector <int> arr1(q);

    for (int i(0); i < q; i++)
        {
        cin >> arr1[i];
        }

    for (int i(0); i < q; i++)
        {
        arr1[i] = arr1[i] - 1;
        }

    int j = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.max_size(); i++)
        {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
            arr[i] = j;
            j++;
            }
        }

    cout << endl << arr.capacity() << endl << endl;
    int z = 1;
    int i = arr.max_size() - 1;

    if (arr.max_size() > 3)
        {
        while (i > 0)
            {
            if (arr[i] > 0)
                {
                while (z < arr.max_size() - 2)
                    {
                    if (arr[i - z] == 0)
                        {
                        swap(arr[i], arr[i - z]);
                        z = 1;
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        z++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            i--;
            }
        }
    else
        {
        while (i > 0)
            {
            if (arr[i] > 0)
                {
                while (z < arr.max_size())
                    {
                    if (arr[i - z] == 0)
                        {
                        swap(arr[i], arr[i - z]);
                        z = 1;
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        z++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            i--;
            }
        }

    for (int jok(0); jok < arr1.max_size(); jok++)
        {
        cout << arr[arr1[jok]] << endl;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Я пробовал size и max_size, оба варианта вызывают исключения.

Comment: у меня всегда возникает вопрос - почему многие используют постинкремент в цикле?  Вы знаете разницу между i++  и ++i? Да, верно, постинкремент создает временное переменное. и это плохо влияет на эффективность, Так зачем не писать преинкремент, если это занимает не больше символов и не влияет на логику?.. (p.s.  это не имеет отношения к вопросу...)

Answer (score 3):

Так, на всякий случай - вы в курсе, что `max_size()` возвращает не размер вектора, а сколько элементов он **может** содержать в принципе?

Вот вы и выскакиваете, мягко говоря, **очень** далеко...

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас ошибки в вычислении индекса элемента. Например в цикле `for (int i = 0; i < arr.max_size(); i++)`. Вместо `max_size` должно быть просто `size`.